# Is it possible to have a circular activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, modal-dialog, geometry, drawing

We know that default shape of Activities is rectangular in Android. I have made a modal activity using the following style:

```
<style name="Theme.TransparentD0" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/semi_transparentD0</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

Now I have a rectangular modal Activity. Is it possible to create a **circular shaped** modal Activity? How?

I mean I want to change the shape of my modal Activity to **Circle**.

Comment: If your background is circular won't it be circular ? I mean what exactly are you sking for? Us to change the shape??

Comment: I mean I want to change the shape of my modal Activity to Circle.

Comment: But if your background is a circle. And every picture is circular. Your activity would look circular. So..... Doesn't that become a designer problem. I'm sorry but I fail to see how this is a programming question?

Comment: Maybe you could clarify? What would your approach be to changing it?

Comment: the black area in my activity is the default LinearLayout. The shape of a LinearLayout is rectangular. How can I make it Circular?

Comment: If it is easy please send me a sample

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create `Dialog` based `Activity`.

Set theme for your `Activity` in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<android:name="YourActivity"
   ...
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>
```

in `YourActivity class` create your carousel `Gallery`

***Create such kind of Layout for Activity***:
[image]

*This is the sample layout:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.sits.TaxiMoldova"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/backgroundCircleImage"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="button 1"
                android:id="@+id/button"/>

        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="button 2"
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Resources:** 
*circle with transparent background[image]*

**Result:**
[image]

Background **is not** black, 100%. Instead of that black background would be your Activity (parent of Modal Activity).
This is the idea, play around with the proportions and everything will be fine :)

Comment: How can I make it Circular?

Comment: what kind of meaning you put in the word "circular"? "Circular" - in the form of a circle?

Comment: Exactly what I need. Can you give me a sample? How to create it?

Comment: Your solution is OK for my problem. But for common smaller rectangular Activities it is possible for user to click the behind activity using `LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL` flag and in your solution it is impossible.

Comment: For example in my code that its picture is in question, I can make it possible for user to click on elements of parent Activity which is around the modal activity.

Comment: I think it is possible, your activity can fill all device screen area, and also can fill just part of screen in center. Or you can create layout (like in sample) and set this layout for your Dialog like content (setContentView() method)

Comment: In that situation the area between rectangular activity and circular picture (corners) is transparent but it is not clickable and user can not click parent Activity's elements that are located in that are.

Comment: yeah, you are right. This link can be useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705023/how-to-make-transparent-area-as-untouchable-for-imageview-in-android. Or you can disable touch for background circle image (have not tried it, this is the idea)